# How to implement nested routing in Angular (16+) using stand-alone components

Tags: angular, angular-router

I would like to achieve nested routing using two separate route configs and two router-outlets. However, I run into the problem that I can't provide Routes in my stand-alone component that is loaded in a router-outlet itself.

What I would like to achieve without (if possible) adding all my router paths to my app routing:
[Structure I would like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4kWx.png)

I tried providing routes to my component (Two Component, see previous image) that is loaded inside a router-outlet itself:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

export const twoRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'three',
        loadComponent: () => import('./three.component').then(a => a.ThreeComponent),
    },
    {
        path: 'four',
        loadComponent: () => import('./four.component').then(a => a.FourComponent),
    },
];

@Component({
    selector: 'app-two',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
    providers: [provideRouter(twoRoutes)],
    template: `
        <div>Hello Component TWO</div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    styles: ``,
})
export class TwoComponent {}
```

Error:
[using provideRouter in a stand-alone component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgFGp.png)

I expected there to be a way to define my nested routes in my stand-alone component instead of having to add all of these router paths to my app routes and children.

**UPDATE:**
I figured out the following works using `loadChildren`, yet I personally do not like this since this requires me to update the app Routes, making it aware of nested routes:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'one',
        loadComponent: () => import('./one.component').then(a => a.OneComponent),
    },
    {
        path: 'two',
        loadComponent: () => import('./two.component').then(a => a.TwoComponent),
        loadChildren: () => import('./two.component').then(t => t.twoRoutes),
    },
];
```

Comment: For multiple router-outlets you will need to use a named outlet. Use loadComponent OR loadchildren. https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#description
I personally do not exactly know what you are trying to achieve but the router is like the app composition and decouples the components from each other.

Comment: @SirOneOfMany, what i would like to achieve, if possible, is to not define my complete application routing in a single Routes object, being it directly or via `loadChildren`. As you mention it is like the "app composition", so it might very well not be possible.

Comment: Ok what you are trying to do is inherently not possible. The router IS in fact a layer of coupling, but more loosely than using components within components.
At some level you will need to wire everything up. I will provide an answer which might not solve your problem, but maybe explains some concepts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood you would like to have like decoupled routing definitions. So that your feature routes do not need to be provided within the root route object.

loadChildren is indeed the correct choice here. Routing IS a way of coupling dependencies, but do it loosely instead of strong coupling like using your components within other components (the component tree is strong coupling).

The following pattern is broadly used as I have seen it quite often.

Let's assume you have an application which consists of features

- SomeApp

  - Car Management Feature
  - Employee  Management Feature

Now what I understood is that you do not want the app routes to be in any way dependent on Car Management Feature or Employee Management Feature.
Where is the point? Your application consists of both features, so it should know the features. But what is possible, to let the app routes only "see" the features route object (imports omitted):

```
export const employeeManagementRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    // component: TwoComponent, // do not define a component here, instead just define child routes
    children: [
      {
        path: 'vacation-calendar',
        component: VacationCalendarComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'employees',
        // component: EmployeeListComponent,
        children: async () => (await loadChildren('./some-other-subfeature')).subFeatureRoutes
      },
      {
         path: '',
         pathMatch: 'full',
         component: EmployeeManagementRootComponent
      }
      {
        path: '**', // route every undefined route to the root of this feature
        redirectTo: ''
      }
    ],
  },
];
```

And therefore in your app-routes.ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'one',
        loadComponent: () => import('./one.component').then(a => a.OneComponent),
    },
    {
        path: 'employee-management',
        // do not use loadComponent here as you do not want to leak the internals of your feature into your app
        loadChildren: () => import('./employee-management/routes').then(feature => feature.employeeManagementRoutes),
    },
];
```

What you would like to do is turning this around and having the feature know how to be routed to. This does not make sense as there is only ONE Router for the entire application which therefore needs to know the routes on its own.
The router is used to provide a way of loosely coupling components and compose an application.

Angular changed the way of routing to be an array of routes instead of a clunky router module. Please do not use modules anymore (i hope they will deprecate modules in the future as they do not serve purpose anymore).
With this new approach the only dependency that an application has to it's features is this routes array.

Defining the routes as a static field of a feature component destroys this whole loosely coupling idea as you will have a dependency to the component class then.

The whole routing tree must be either known on bootstrapping or lazy loaded via loadChildren.

What comes close to what you would like to achieve might be microfrontends with module federation:

https://www.angulararchitects.io/blog/the-microfrontend-revolution-part-2-module-federation-with-angular/

But even here does to composing application know it's dependencies.

Conclusion:

With the router you are able to decouple features from each other. With angulars provideRouter() function and loadChildren loading another route array it is even possible to decouple your app from it's features internals. No need to load a component, just load the feature routes and let the feature decide everything else.

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE

If you do not want to go the standalone route, you need to use angular classic method of routing with modules, the most important point to note is that we need to use `component` in the routes, if we use `loadComponent` then the component must be a standalone component!

two module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TwoComponent } from './two.component';
import { ThreeComponent } from './three/three.component';
import { FourComponent } from './four/four.component';
import { TwoRoutingModule } from './two.routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, TwoRoutingModule, CommonModule],
  declarations: [TwoComponent, ThreeComponent, FourComponent],
})
export class TwoModule {}
```

two routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FourComponent } from './four/four.component';
import { ThreeComponent } from './three/three.component';
import { TwoComponent } from './two.component';

const twoRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TwoComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'three',
        component: ThreeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'four',
        component: FourComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(twoRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class TwoRoutingModule {}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jjbepr)

---

Very nice question!

I think you need to provide the `provideRouter` only at the root level and all other imports are derived using the `loadChildren`, please find below the working example for your reference. Through this method all components needs to be standalone, you can also use a module if needed.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { RouterModule, Routes, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'one',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./one/one.component').then((a) => a.OneComponent),
  },
  {
    path: 'two',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./two/two.component').then((a) => a.TwoComponent),
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./two/two.component').then((t) => {
        console.log(t.TwoComponent.twoRoutes);
        return t.TwoComponent.twoRoutes;
      }),
  },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule],
  template: `
  <a routerLink="/one">one</a> | 
  <a routerLink="/two">two</a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes)],
});
```

two component

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-two',
  template: `
  <br/>
  <a routerLink="./three">three</a> | 
  <a routerLink="./four">four</a>
  <div>Hello Component TWO</div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
  providers: [],
  styleUrls: ['./two.component.css'],
})
export class TwoComponent {
  static twoRoutes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'three',
      loadComponent: () =>
        import('../three/three.component').then((a) => a.ThreeComponent),
    },
    {
      path: 'four',
      loadComponent: () =>
        import('../four/four.component').then((a) => a.FourComponent),
    },
  ];
}
```

[working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hhatkg)

Comment: Thank you for your example. The code you provide indeed works as expected. However, it still requires the "nested routing" to be part of the top-level Routes object, via `loadChildren`. I'm wondering if there is a way to decouple that.

Answer (score 0):

Note that using `loadChildren` will make your subroutes lazy-loaded.
probably nothing wrong with it, but if you don't want this side-effect,
I found another way to do it. Just use provideRouter several times like this. Subroutes must go before routes

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
providers: [
    provideRouter(subroutes),
    provideRouter(routes),
],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```